# Whose Access Key and Secret Key is required for communication with IoT Core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

The MQTT over WebSocket protocol only supports the Signature version 4 (SigV4) authentication. To do so, the wss://endpoint URL will need to be signed using an Access Key and a Secret Key.

Questions: Whose Access Key and Secret Key? An IAM user's?

Comment: It can be IAM user or role, as long as they have permissions to interact with IoT.

Comment: Do you mean that the access key is the IAM username and secrey ket is that IAM password for that IAM username?

Comment: Its not user name. Its special key and secret key for [programatic access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys).

Comment: Where can I get this value - is this per user or per accont?

Comment: You can generate them for IAM user in `IAM->Users->selected_user->Security credentials->Access keys`

Comment: They key you mention above refers to an IAM user. However, the key that I am asking for is for the device. Do you mean we need to create an user per device?